# establish a user interface - Functions of an operating system

Tags: operating-systems

i was reading about the functions of an operating system and i found the following :

> An operating system has three main functions: (1) manage the
>   computer's resources, such as the central processing unit, memory,
>   disk drives, and printers, (2) establish a user interface, and (3)
>   execute and provide services for applications software.

what is meant by establish a user interface ? does it mean graphical interfaces that the os has ? or software interface or what ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user interface is your "user input/output" hardware (screen, keyboard, mouse etc.) as well as the software (e.g. the GUI or a command line).